# How to get progress on BQ file load

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

When importing a large csv (or other type) file to BigQuery, how can we get the progress of the import? For example, if we have a 1TB file and use the import csv command, I don't just want to wait there ten hours for the file to import. How can we get the progress, or is this not possible?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data

Right now, we're not able to get it until the csv file has been loaded

---

Regarding progress bar:

Load Task specific statistics is never returned while task is in progress. Statistics only contain start/end time and Java API parses it into CopyStatistics class instead.

```
{
 "kind": "bigquery#job",
 "etag": "\"smpMas70-D1-zV2oEH0ud6qY21c/crKHebm6x2NXA6pCjE8znB7dp-E\"",
 "id": "YYY:job_l9TWVQ64YjKx7BgDufu2gReMEL0",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/YYY/jobs/job_l9TWVQ64YjKx7BgDufu2gReMEL0",
 "jobReference": {
  "projectId": "YYY",
  "jobId": "job_l9TWVQ64YjKx7BgDufu2gReMEL0"
 },
 "configuration": {
  "load": {
   "sourceUris": [
    "gs://datadocs/afdfb50f-cbc2-47d4-985e-080cadefc963"
   ],
   "schema": {
    "fields": [
       ...
    ]
   },
   "destinationTable": {
    "projectId": "YYY",
    "datasetId": "1aaf1682dbc2403e92a0a0ed8534581f",
    "tableId": "ORIGIN"
   },
   "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
   "writeDisposition": "WRITE_EMPTY",
   "fieldDelimiter": ",",
   "skipLeadingRows": 1,
   "quote": "\"",
   "maxBadRecords": 1000,
   "allowQuotedNewlines": true,
   "sourceFormat": "CSV"
  }
 },
 "status": {
  "state": "RUNNING"
 },
 "statistics": {
  "creationTime": "1490868448431",
  "startTime": "1490868449147"
 },
 "user_email": "YYY@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Load statistics is only returned in the end, when whole CSV file has been imported.

---

How do we get the progress while it's being uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [statistics.load.outputBytes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#statistics.load.outputBytes)

> Per documentation - while a load job is in the running state, this
>   value may change

You can experiment with it - if this can be used as progress metric via call to [Jobs: get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get)

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to work -- see updated question please.

Comment: i've just experimented with much smaller file and got same experience, but thought it might be because of small file  - hoping that this would be different for 1TB file. Thank you for updating with your results! I think the `change` mentioned in documentation either not correct (less likely) or relevant for multi-file load scenario - never had chance to play with this as in my environment when we load files (which not that frequent anymore as we moved to streaming) we make sure they are up to 256MB and then have progress handled on our side